# How to specify a file for environment variables for docker

Tags: docker

I have a few environment variables that I need inside of my code.

And when I starts building a docker container, I wish to bake those environment variables into my docker container.

I understand that the dockerfile directive 'ENV' does exactly that, I wonder if there is a way to point to an file instead of writing it inside of the Dockerfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such way to inject environment variables using a file during the build step using Dockerfile. However, in most cases, people do end up using an `entrypoint` script & injecting variables during the `docker run` or `docker-compose up`.

In case it's a necessity you might need to write a shell wrapper which will change the values in the `Dockerfile` dynamically by taking a key-value pair text file as an input or make it something as below but the ENV file name need to be included in Dockerfile as suggested by @thaJeztah in [link](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28617) -

```
COPY my-env-vars /    
RUN export $(cat my-env-vars | xargs)
```

It's an open issue - 
https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/28617

Comment: This is a neat hack. I will do this for now

Comment: Yeah, takes away a lot of pain of managing variables individually in the Dockerfile. Gad that it helped!

Comment: @vivekyad4v Environment variables are useful so that the same container can be run on different environments without having to re-build them. With your "hack" to take away this portability and you hardcode values inside the image. You also expose environment variable values for everybody to see by only investigating the image.

Comment: @Mihai - Since it's a hack we don't expect it to be perfect. I have clearly mentioned the pros and cons(ENV file name need to be included in Dockerfile). If you have access to docker you can easily get the environment variables in container/images etc, doesn't matter how it's injected. It would be great if you can share a better hack or a full-fledged solution to it.

Comment: @vivekyad4v I did post my solution :) Plus I am not a big fan of "hacks" so I wouldn't post one. Again, I am not against your solution but I do think you should make the user aware of the issues created by this solution which I didn't see in your post. Also I don't think you understood my comment: docker images end up on public repositories. Containers don't.So images can be inspected by anybody with access to the registry.To inspect a container you need a lot more than that (firstly access to host).So in that there is a big difference between images and containers and their security concerns.

Comment: Yes, agree. I won't suggest this hack to use in Production environments for critical applications.

Answer (score 1):

At build time, ENV variables are not available. You need to use ARG variables. For that you have the "--build-arg" flag of "docker build". It doesn't take in a file thou.

ENV variables are used by a running container and can be injected as a file using the "--env-file" flag of "docker run".

Hopefully this is what you were looking for otherwise let me know more in detail.